# Adding Custom Data Layer Variables for Brightcove Video Tracking

Tags: google-tag-manager, brightcove

I'm looking to track custom timings of Brightcove videos with Google Tag Manager. I have a tag set up that tracks Brightcove's default data layer values, which include Media Play/Pause, Media Begin, and % Milestone Passed. However, I'm not sure if there's a way to track custom timings beyond this standard set that Brightcove tracks? I haven't found documentation outlining how to do this.

I followed the process in this article to set up tracking: https://iabramo.com/2016/03/08/track-brightcove-player-with-google-tag-manager/

If anyone has advice on how to track custom timings (ie. at 1 minute, 53 seconds), please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Elizabeth,

We recently released a Google Tag Manager Plugin for use with the Brightcove Player. Using that, you can configure custom dimensions in addition to the standard ones track by GA.

In the docs, there is a reference to a dimension called `bcvideo_video_milestone` which might be able to be set to 1 min 53 seconds if that is the milestone you want to trigger an event for.

https://support.brightcove.com/google-tag-manager-plugin-brightcove-player